# estimation of standard errors after logistic regression

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

i have following data

```
Pass    Hours
0   0.5
0   0.75
0   1
0   1.25
0   1.5
0   1.75
1   1.75
0   2
1   2.25
0   2.5
1   2.75
0   3
1   3.25
0   3.5
1   4
1   4.25
1   4.5
1   4.75
1   5
1   5.5
```

and i want to test whether number of hours of studying can help me  to predict  passing in subject,  i have estimated everything in excel, here is my calculations
[image: calculation of logistic regression]

in wikipedia, there is also such kind of information about coefficients
[image]

i would like to know step by step how to calculate
1. standard errors 
2.Z value
3. P value

for standard errors i found following formulas
[image]

i have calculated predicted values for estimated coefficients

```
predicted
0.034711145
0.049773969
0.070893216
0.100030106
0.139346146
0.190838272
0.190838272
0.255704879
0.33353166
0.421627469
0.515011185
0.607358348
0.692616526
0.766479707
0.87444625
0.910276501
0.936622684
0.955609901
0.969096422
0.985194054
```

and i have calculated errors

```
residual
-0.034711145
-0.049773969
-0.070893216
-0.100030106
-0.139346146
-0.190838272
0.809161728
-0.255704879
0.66646834
-0.421627469
0.484988815
-0.607358348
0.307383474
-0.766479707
0.12555375
0.089723499
0.063377316
0.044390099
0.030903578
0.014805946
```

but now how to calculate? pleas  help me to continue, thanks in advance

EDITED : on the  based on this  tutorial
[How to compute the standard errors of a logistic regression's coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89484/how-to-compute-the-standard-errors-of-a-logistic-regressions-coefficients)

i have estimated  standard errors  and  z values in matlab   and excel, how let p values(Wald test), how can i do it?

Comment: You call this "logistic regression," yet you fit responses that are non-integral and you quote formulas for ordinary least squares regression.  Please tell us what your model actually is.

Comment: it is logistic regression my friend, i run logistic regression

Comment: how can i upload  excel file itself?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on an Excel file to explain your problem.  State your problem and your assumptions directly in your post here.

Comment: i already posted my friend, i have estimated coefficients of logistic regression, now i need to estimate other statsitical parameters,  standard errors, and p values

Comment: You are using some strange mixture of formulas.  Although the spreadsheet looks a little like the calculations to maximize the likelihood in logistic regression, the residuals and the formulas you quote are not for logistic regression at all.

Comment: @whuber  i have a ready excel file, i can upload it for you, i can't overwrite this poste with screenshots, let me show you excel file and see yourself

Comment: where can i upload?

Comment: i have estimated   standard errors and z value, now what about p values

Comment: There is no service at SE for file upload. Find some of many places on the internet, and post a link here.