# Confidence interval for predicted probabilities

Tags: r, logistic, confidence-interval, multinomial-distribution

I fitted the following multinomial regression:

```
library(car)
p1<-c(1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,3,2,2,2,3,4,3,3,4,3,4)

d1<-c(1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2,2,2,1)

d1<-as.ordered(d1)

library(nnet)
test<-multinom(p1~d1)
predi<-expand.grid(d1=c("1","2","3","4"))

pre<-predict(test,predi,type="probs")
```

The output is a table of the predicted probabilities for every coefficient. I can also order the results for the confidence interval of the coefficents with:

```
confint(test)
```

My question is: is it possible to get the results for the confidence interval for the predicted probabilities? It means for every amount in the "pre" output! 
PS: I found a similar question here in 
["plotting confidence intervals"][1][Plotting confidence intervals for the predicted probabilities from a logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29044/plotting-confidence-intervals-for-the-predicted-probabilities-from-a-logistic-re)

The main answer is perfect for my question, but I do not know how to combine with multinomial regression. 
I hope you understand my bad english :) Thank you for your help

Comment: You may calculate them yourself using the SEs you get from `summary(test)`...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.hmm...how should I do this? Do you have a concrete idea?

Comment: You mean mathematically? You know how to calculate a CI (if not, look it up!!)? Try to replicate the CIs you get from `confint(test)` and then you can go on...

Comment: My problem is, that I do not know how to calculate predicted probabilities with my test results and my CI in R.

Comment: It would be great, to get some more advices. I don't know how to build this in R. The problem is, that I have problems to rebuild the predict() output and with it the CI for the predicted probabilities. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with the `effects` package. Now, for a reproducible example:

```
library(nnet)

set.seed(892)

x <- c(rnorm(100, 10, 1))

y <- factor(rep_len(1:3, 100))

fit <- multinom(y ~ x)
```

That's the model, now let's get some predicted probabilities.

```
fit.eff <- Effect("x", fit)
data.frame(fit.eff$model.matrix, fit.eff$prob, fit.eff$lower.prob, 
           fit.eff$upper.prob)

  X.Intercept.  x   prob.X1   prob.X2   prob.X3 L.prob.X1  L.prob.X2 L.prob.X3 U.prob.X1 U.prob.X2 U.prob.X3
1            1  8 0.4211010 0.1119309 0.4669680 0.2218766 0.03696574 0.2565056 0.6498212 0.2927143 0.6898823
2            1  9 0.3962450 0.1958841 0.4078709 0.2704241 0.10428467 0.2805946 0.5374796 0.3376147 0.5488354
3            1 10 0.3478412 0.3198070 0.3323518 0.2583849 0.23216366 0.2442887 0.4494968 0.4223378 0.4339321
4            1 11 0.2780225 0.4753991 0.2465784 0.1689652 0.33171768 0.1449846 0.4217471 0.6232722 0.3871286
```

Which gives the probabilities for factor "1" in X, `prob.X1`, its lower confidence interval `L.prob.X1` and its upper interval `U.prob.X1`.

`effects` will helpfully plot the values for you as well, which is its main purpose anyway.

```
plot(fit.eff)
```

[image]

Edit: added some code to clarify which levels of `x` were being predicted. Note that `Effect()` automatically cuts numerical predictor variables based on `grid.pretty`, which might not be what you typically want. In this case, you need to set the `xlevels` option, like this: `fit.eff <- effect("x", fit, xlevels = list(x = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)))`.