# Calculate prediction error for a multinomial output like in the "effects" package

Tags: r, prediction, nnet

After fitting a multinomial model to my data with the "multinom" function (package nnet), I want to show the effect of selected variables controlling for other variable values. I know that the "effects" package do mainly what I want, but I want to be able to calculate the prediction error (confidence interval) by myself. 
Does someone could tell me the methodology and if possible the R code?
I think we should use the delta method, but I'm not sure how to apply it in this case.

Here is a small example code (based on data available in the effects package)

```
library(nnet)
library(effects)
mod <- multinom(vote ~ age + gender, data=BEPS)
summary(mod)

# Call:
# multinom(formula = vote ~ age + gender, data = BEPS)

# Coefficients:
#                  (Intercept)         age gendermale
# Labour             1.2241862 -0.01562320  0.1682676
# Liberal Democrat   0.4979706 -0.01551381  0.1240998

# Std. Errors:
#                  (Intercept)         age gendermale
# Labour             0.2277826 0.003830006  0.1204621
# Liberal Democrat   0.2694373 0.004578836  0.1436882

# Residual Deviance: 3186.266 
# AIC: 3198.266 

plot(allEffects(mod))
```

[image: output of the effect function]

The only thing I need is to be able to calculate the values of errors shown in this graph !

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Request for mini-tutorials when not accompanied by code that creates an appropriate demonstration set get my close vote. The text in the close dialog that I choose is: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Requesting migration.

Comment: @BondedDust I added some code and a figure to explain my query. Hope this meet your requirements!

Comment: @BondedDust I also tried to find the answer reading the R code from the function, but the R code of the Effect function call a C code ... then I do not understand what is done ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67460/confidence-interval-for-predicted-probabilities.