# Calculating confidence intervals for a logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, standard-error

I'm using a binomial logistic regression to identify if exposure to `has_x` or `has_y` impacts the likelihood that a user will click on something. My model is the following:

```r
fit = glm(formula = has_clicked ~ has_x + has_y, 
          data=df, 
          family = binomial())
```

This the output from my model:

```r
Call:
glm(formula = has_clicked ~ has_x + has_y, 
    family = binomial(), data = active_domains)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.9869  -0.9719  -0.9500   1.3979   1.4233  

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          -0.504737   0.008847 -57.050  < 2e-16 ***
has_xTRUE -0.056986   0.010201  -5.586 2.32e-08 ***
has_yTRUE  0.038579   0.010202   3.781 0.000156 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 217119  on 164182  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 217074  on 164180  degrees of freedom
AIC: 217080

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

As each coefficient is significant, using this model I'm able to tell what the value of any of these combinations is using the following approach:

```r
predict(fit, data.frame(has_x = TRUE, has_y=TRUE), type = "response")
```

I don't understand how I can report on the Std. Error of the prediction.

1. Do I just need to use $1.96*SE$? Or do I need to convert the
   $SE$ using an approach described [here](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/convert_logit2prob/)?
2. If I want to understand the standard-error for both variables
   how would I consider that?

Unlike this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5304/why-is-there-a-difference-between-manually-calculating-a-logistic-regression-95), I am interested in understanding what the upper and lower bounds of the error are in a percentage. For example, of my prediction shows a value of 37% for `True,True` can I calculate that this is $+/- 0.3%$ for a $95\% CI$? (0.3% chosen to illustrate my point)

Comment: Duplicate:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5304/why-is-there-a-difference-between-manually-calculating-a-logistic-regression-95

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there a difference between manually calculating a logistic regression 95% confidence interval, and using the confint() function in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5304/why-is-there-a-difference-between-manually-calculating-a-logistic-regression-95)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen are you sure it is a duplicate as the OP seems to want a prediction interval but seems to be working on the OR scale rather than the log scale which may be the root of the problem?

Comment: I clarified why I believe this question is different to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5304/why-is-there-a-difference-between-manually-calculating-a-logistic-regression-95

Comment: If you want to evaluate how good a logistic regression predicts, one usually uses different measures than prediction + SE. One popular evaluation measure ist the ROC-Curve with respective AUC

Comment: Could this be of any help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414842/confidence-interval-of-probability-prediction-from-logistic-regression-statsmode

Comment: @mdewey: I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Your question may come from the fact that you are dealing with Odds Ratios and Probabilities which is confusing at first. Since the logistic model is a non linear transformation of $\beta^Tx$ computing the confidence intervals is not as straightforward.

### Background

Recall that for the Logistic regression model

- **Probability** of $(Y = 1)$: $p = \frac{e^{\alpha + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2 
  x_2}}{1 + e^{ \alpha + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2 x_2}}$
- **Odds** of $(Y = 1)$: $ \left( \frac{p}{1-p}\right) = e^{\alpha + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2 
  x_2}$
- **Log Odds** of $(Y = 1)$: $ \log \left( \frac{p}{1-p}\right) = \alpha + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2 
  x_2$

Consider the case where you have a one unit increase in variable $x_1$, i.e. $x_1 + 1$, then the new odds are

$$ \text{Odds}(Y = 1) = e^{\alpha + \beta_1(x_1 + 1) + \beta_2x_2}  = e^{\alpha + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_1 + \beta_2x_2 } $$

- **Odds Ratio (OR)** are therefore

$$ \frac{\text{Odds}(x_1 + 1)}{\text{Odds}(x_1)} = \frac{e^{\alpha + \beta_1(x_1 + 1) + \beta_2x_2}  }{e^{\alpha + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2x_2}} = e^{\beta_1}  $$

- **Log Odds Ratio** =  $\beta_1$
- **Relative risk** or (probability ratio) = $\frac{ \frac{e^{\alpha + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 
  x_2}}{1 + e^{ \alpha + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 x_2}}}{ \frac{e^{\alpha + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2 
  x_2}}{1 + e^{ \alpha + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2 x_2}}}$

### Interpreting coefficients

How would you interpret the coefficient value $\beta_j$ ? Assuming that everything else remains fixed:

- For every unit increase in $x_j$ the log-odds ratio increases by $\beta_j$.
- For every unit increase in $x_j$ the odds ratio increases by $e^{\beta_j}$.
- For every increase of $x_j$ from $k$ to $k + \Delta$ the odds ratio increases by $e^{\beta_j \Delta}$
- If the coefficient is negative, then an increase in $x_j$ leads to a decrease in the odds ratio.

### Confidence intervals for a single parameter $\beta_j$

> Do I just need to use $1.96∗SE$? Or do I need to convert the SE using an approach described here?

Since the parameter $\beta_j$ is estimated using Maxiumum Likelihood Estimation, MLE theory tells us that it is asymptotically normal and hence we can use the large sample **Wald** confidence interval to get the usual

$$ \beta_j \pm z^* SE(\beta_j)$$

Which gives a confidence interval on the log-odds ratio. Using the invariance property of the MLE allows us to exponentiate to get
$$ e^{\beta_j \pm z^* SE(\beta_j)}$$

which is a confidence interval on the odds ratio. Note that these intervals are for a single parameter only.

> If I want to understand the standard-error for both variables how would I consider that?

If you include several parameters you can use the Bonferroni procedure, otherwise for all parameters you can use the confidence interval for probability estimates

### Bonferroni procedure for several parameters

If $g$ parameters are to be estimated with family confidence coefficient of approximately $1 - \alpha$, the joint Bonferroni confidence limits are

$$ \beta_g \pm z_{(1 - \frac{\alpha}{2g})}SE(\beta_g)$$

### Confidence intervals for probability estimates

The logistic model outputs an estimation of the probability of observing a one and we aim to construct a frequentist interval around the true probability $p$ such that $Pr(p_{L} \leq p \leq p_{U}) = .95$

One approach called **endpoint transformation** does the following:

- Compute the upper and lower bounds of the confidence interval for the linear combination $x^T\beta$ (using the Wald CI)
- Apply a monotonic transformation to the endpoints $F(x^T\beta)$ to obtain the probabilities.

Since $Pr(x^T\beta) = F(x^T\beta)$ is a monotonic transformation of $x^T\beta$

$$ [Pr(x^T\beta)_L \leq Pr(x^T\beta) \leq Pr(x^T\beta)_U] = [F(x^T\beta)_L \leq F(x^T\beta) \leq F(x^T\beta)_U] $$

Concretely this means computing $\beta^Tx \pm z^* SE(\beta^Tx)$ and then applying the logit transform to the result to get the lower and upper bounds:

$$[\frac{e^{x^T\beta - z^* SE(x^T\beta)}}{1 + e^{x^T\beta - z^* SE(x^T\beta)}}, \frac{e^{x^T\beta + z^* SE(x^T\beta)}}{1 + e^{x^T\beta + z^* SE(x^T\beta)}},] $$

The estimated approximate variance of $x^T\beta$ can be calculated using the covariance matrix of the regression coefficients using

$$ Var(x^T\beta) = x^T \Sigma x$$

The advantage of this method is that the bounds cannot be outside the range $(0,1)$

There are several other approaches as well, using the delta method, bootstrapping etc.. which each have their own assumptions, advantages and limits.

---

#### Sources and info

My favorite book on this topic is *"Applied Linear Statistical Models"* by Kutner, Neter, Li, Chapter 14

Otherwise here are a few online sources:

- [Plotting confidence intervals for the predicted probabilities from a logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29044/plotting-confidence-intervals-for-the-predicted-probabilities-from-a-logistic-re)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414842/confidence-interval-of-probability-prediction-from-logistic-regression-statsmode

#### Edit October 2021 - New links

- https://fdocuments.net/reader/full/5logreg-beamer-online
- https://jslsoc.sitehost.iu.edu/stata/ci_computations/xulong-prvalue-23aug2005.pdf

Comment: Much of this is about CI for the coefficients which is a fine thing for the OP to know about but are we sure that is what he needs? You later section seems to me more relevant but perhaps the distinctions may be missed if read too quickly?

Comment: Yes you are probably right - but understanding odds, log odds and probabilities for log regression is something I struggled with in the past - I hope this post summarises the topic well enough to such that it might help someone in the future. Perhaps I could answer the question more explicitly by providing a CI but we would need the covariance matrix

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what do you mean by: "Compute the upper and lower bounds of the confidence interval for the linear combination xTβ (using the Wald CI)" - how exactly do you do this?

Comment: Also, could you explain how your method differs than what is suggested in the next answer - i.e. calculating the ci for prediction, and then transforming the prediction.

Comment: @DavidRefaeli see full derivation here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163824/different-ways-to-produce-a-confidence-interval-for-odds-ratio-from-logistic-reg/365159#365159

Comment: @XavierBourretSicotte: Great answer! I have a follow up question: you mentioned bootstrap as an alternative method to estimate confidence intervals for coefficients and probabilities in logistic. Do you know of a reference or quick explanation for how the bootstrap CI estimation works?

Comment: Some of the links you shared in the "Sources and Info" section have been deleted. Find below the links to (what I think are) the same same resources in other locations:

* https://fdocuments.net/reader/full/5logreg-beamer-online
* https://mheaton.byu.edu/docs/files/Stat330/InClassAnalyses/7%20-%20CHD/LectureNotes/LogisticRegression.pdf
* https://jslsoc.sitehost.iu.edu/stata/ci_computations/xulong-prvalue-23aug2005.pdf

Answer (score 6):

To get the 95% confidence interval of the prediction you can calculate on the logit scale and then convert those back to the probability scale 0-1. Here is an example using the titanic dataset.

```r
library(titanic)
data("titanic_train")

titanic_train$Pclass = factor(titanic_train$Pclass, 
    levels = c(1, 2, 3), labels = c('First', 'Second', 'Third'))

fit = glm(Survived ~ Sex + Pclass, data=titanic_train, 
          family = binomial())

inverse_logit = function(x){
  exp(x)/(1+exp(x))
}

predicted = predict(fit, data.frame(Sex='male', Pclass='First'), 
                    type='link', se.fit=TRUE)

se_high = inverse_logit(predicted$fit + (predicted$se.fit*1.96))
se_low = inverse_logit(predicted$fit - (predicted$se.fit*1.96))
expected = inverse_logit(predicted$fit)
```

The mean and low/high 95% CI.

```r
> expected
        1 
0.4146556 
> se_high
        1 
0.4960988 
> se_low
        1 
0.3376243
```

And the output from just using `type='response'`, which only gives the mean

```r
predict(fit, data.frame(Sex='male', Pclass='First'), type='response')
        1 
0.4146556
```

Comment: ```predict(fit, data.frame(Sex='male', Pclass='First'), type='response', se.fit=TRUE)``` will work.

Answer (score 0):

The explanations above are very nice and detailed.
Here is the simple way to just get the result:
Random data frame:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
          trial = factor(c(rep("noise", 340), rep("signal", 340))),
          rating = c(rep(1, 70), rep(2, 67), rep(3, 28), 
                 rep(4, 45), rep(5, 53), rep(6, 77), rep(1, 219), 
                 rep(2, 56), rep(3, 16), rep(4, 24), rep(5, 14), rep(6, 11))
)
```

-- >sadly the following edit is not being presented correct: here will be dat-"dollar"-rating and dat-dollar-trial to edit the data frame above

```r
dat$rating <- as.factor(ifelse(dat$rating <= 3, "sure", "not"))
dat$trial <- ifelse(dat$trial == "noise", 0, 1)
```

---

## IMPORTANT

```r
my.glm <- glm(trial ~ rating, family = binomial(probit), data = dat)
summary(my.glm)

# 95-CI for all Betas
confint(my.glm)
# 90-CI for all Betas
confint(my.glm, level = 0.90)

# 95-CI of Beta 1
confint(my.glm)[c(2, 4)]
# 90-CI of Beta 1
confint(my.glm, level = 0.90)[c(2, 4)]
```

Comment: Note that `confint` on a glm objects uses another method (and arguably more precise) than in the other answers you refer to, namely profile likelihood.